# Comparing sheets difference

Tags: excel

Lets say I have the following sheets. I want to the following logic of output. If `columnA` value of `Sheet2` exists or does not exists, return a true or false value to another column. At the same time I want to say that if it is true, if sheet1 `columnB` (linked to `columnA`) is different than `sheet2` `columnB` output the difference. See below for example structure and at the bottom I'll output what I'll like to exactly see.

Sheet1:

```
columnA columnB
A          5.5
B          2.2
```

Sheet2:

```
columnA columnB
A          1.1
D          2
```

OUTPUT I'd like to get:

Sheet3

```
columnA       columnB
TRUE            4.4
FALSE           N/A
```

Comment: Could you please explain, which technology you want to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Formula in Sheet 3

For Cell A1 Type in the below Formula and then drag it to copy it to other cells

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A1), CONCATENATE("FALSE", "    N/A"), CONCATENATE("TRUE", "    ", (Sheet1!A1-Sheet2!A1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. in your Sheet3 ..

Formula in A1 `=IF(Sheet1!A1 = Sheet2!A1,TRUE,FALSE)`

Formula in B1 `=IF(A1,ABS(Sheet1!B1 - Sheet2!B1),"N/A")`